# Ferries from Panama to Colombia on the Pacific side?

Tags: ferries, panama, colombia

For walking/biking (or driving) from Mexico to Lima, Perú, the ferries in the Caribbean from Panama to Colombia add a lot of distance.
I could save a lot of road if I could go on the Pacific side.

There are towns/villages in both countries on the coast with no visible roads in aerial photos, so access must be by air or water.

Comment: Assuming there is a ferry at all by the time you get there! For whatever reasons, ferry services on this route don't seem to last very long... Anyway, on the Pacific side there is little but dense forest until you get halfway through Ecuador..

Comment: As far as I can tell there was only 1 service that was running: https://www.facebook.com/ferryxpress/ but that's on the Atlantic side.  You can still sail for about $600 .

Answer (score 1):

There's not much infrastructure in either side of the border, so I don't think there's any ferry service. And even if it did, you won't find any immigration office in the Colombian side (the largest/closest town is Bahia Solano (Ciudad Mutis), and it doesn't have one).

I recommend traveling by the Caribbean if you want to stay on the surface, or fly Panama-Cali, it's possible to find some cheap flights...

Source: I'm a diving instructor and work a lot in the Colombian Pacific.

Comment: I've already returned, and I would have liked to stay on the bicycle.  But the whole point of the question is that the Caribbean ferries would have added hundreds of kilómetros (as I said).